# How to parse BBCode using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this library (https://github.com/DasRed/js-bbcode-parser) to parse some bbcode in JavaScript.

I'm adding a [quote] tag to the library but my regex does not work on the code. When I try it on https://www.regextester.com/ it does match my text.

here is the text I have

```
 [quote:16629e5e6b=\"newUser\"]It's coming down to a marketing challenge[/quote:16629e5e6b]
```

Here is the regex I have for it

```
'\\[quote[\:0-9a-zA-Z=\\"]*\\](.+)\\[/quote[\:0-9a-zA-Z]*\\]': '<div class="quote">$1</div>'
```

here is code with the JS code

```
let bbCode = new BbCodeParser({
      '\\[br\\]': '<br>',

      '\\[b\\](.+)\\[/b\\]': '<strong>$1</strong>',
      '\\[i\\](.+)\\[/i\\]': '<em>$1</em>',
      '\\[u\\](.+)\\[/u\\]': '<u>$1</u>',
      '\\[u[\:a-zA-Z0-9]*?\\](.+)\\[/u[\:a-zA-Z0-9]*?\\]': '<u>$1</u>',

      '\\[h1\\](.+)\\[/h1\\]': '<h1><a href="$1" name="$1">$1</a></h1>',
      '\\[h2\\](.+)\\[/h2\\]': '<h2><a href="$1" name="$1">$1</a></h2>',
      '\\[h3\\](.+)\\[/h3\\]': '<h3><a href="$1" name="$1">$1</a></h3>',
      '\\[h4\\](.+)\\[/h4\\]': '<h4><a href="$1" name="$1">$1</a></h4>',
      '\\[h5\\](.+)\\[/h5\\]': '<h5><a href="$1" name="$1">$1</a></h5>',
      '\\[h6\\](.+)\\[/h6\\]': '<h6><a href="$1" name="$1">$1</a></h6>',

      '\\[p\\](.+)\\[/p\\]': '<p>$1</p>',

      '\\[color=(.+)\\](.+)\\[/color\\]':   '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>',
      '\\[size=([0-9]+)\\](.+)\\[/size\\]': '<span style="font-size:$1px">$2</span>',

      '\\[img\\](.+)\\[/img\\]': '<img src="$1">',
      '\\[img=(.+)\\]':          '<img src="$1">',

      '\\[email\\](.+)\\[/email\\]':      '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>',
      '\\[email=(.+)\\](.+)\\[/email\\]': '<a href="mailto:$1">$2</a>',

      '\\[url\\](.+)\\[/url\\]':                 '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
      '\\[url=(.+)\\|onclick\\](.+)\[/url\]':    '<a onclick="$1">$2</a>',
      '\\[url=(.+)\starget=(.+)\\](.+)\[/url\]': '<a href="$1" target="$2">$3</a>',
      '\\[url=(.+)\\](.+)\\[/url\\]':            '<a href="$1">$2</a>',

      '\\[a=(.+)\\](.+)\\[/a\\]': '<a href="$1" name="$1">$2</a>',

      '\\[list\\](.+)\\[/list\\]': '<ul>$1</ul>',
      '\\[\*\\](.+)\\[/\\*\\]':    '<li>$1</li>',

      '\\[quote\\](.+)\\[/quote\\]': '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>',
      '\\[quote[\:0-9a-zA-Z=\\"]*\\](.+)\\[/quote[\:0-9a-zA-Z]*\\]': '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>',

      '\\[google\\](.+)\\[/google\\]': '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'
    });
```

thanks for the help

Comment: The referenced library documentation suggests using `bbCodeParser.create({ ... });` to provide custom BBCodes, however your example is not using `.create( ... )`. While I'm not familiar with the library, I'm curious as to whether you've tried that? Are you getting any errors in console with your current code? And can you include a minimal snippet of how/where you're calling the `.parse(...)` function?

Comment: @TylerRoper I'm updating that library to include a few other custom bbcode by default. I don't get any error, it just does not match my tag. I added 2 other tags and they are working fine, just the quotes I cannot get it to match.

Comment: I believe that perhaps [this](https://regexr.com/3pkks) is the RegEx you're looking for: `\[quote[\:0-9a-zA-Z=\\"]*\](.+)\[\/quote[\:0-9a-zA-Z]*\]`. Escaped for JavaScript, I'd imagine it would look like this: `\\[quote[\\:0-9a-zA-Z=\\\\"]*\\](.+)\\[\\/quote[\\:0-9a-zA-Z]*\\]`

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks for the help with the regex. It worked.